# How to find and click the link using “onclick” with Selenium/Python which includes quotes or double quotes?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

How to find and click the link where “onclick” attribute value includes quotes? An Example below:-

```
<li onclick="StoreSessionifo('09:30 PM','84609','0023','SCREEN 1','2019-08-18T21:30:00','HO00005319');">
<a>09:30 PM</a>
<span class="info-mexperience">2D</span>
</li>
```

Comment: The `onclick` event belongs to the `<li>` parent tag. I think you need to click either `<a>` or `<span>` child tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xpath`, utilizing the `contains` function, follow the following functions :

```
//tagname[contains(@attribute,"partialcontents")]
```

In your case, please try :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[contains(@onclick,"84609")]').click()
```